# How to subset a data.frame in a list and return data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

When subsetting a data.frame inside of a list, I get vectors instead of a data.frames (see the example below). How to avoid this and get a data.frames?

```
l <- list(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3)), data.frame(b=c(4,5,6,5)), data.frame(c=c(3,4,5,6)))
names(l) <- c("A", "B", "C")
l
lapply(l, function(x) x[2:nrow(x), ])
```

output

```
> l <- list(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3)), data.frame(b=c(4,5,6,5)), data.frame(c=c(3,4,5,6)))
> names(l) <- c("A", "B", "C")
> l
$A
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3

$B
  b
1 4
2 5
3 6
4 5

$C
  c
1 3
2 4
3 5
4 6

> lapply(l, function(x) x[2:nrow(x), ])
$A
[1] 2 3

$B
[1] 5 6 5

$C
[1] 4 5 6
```

Comment: `lapply` returns a *list* not a *vector* as you claim.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I mean a vectors inside of a list.

Comment: @Dirk: Technically a list *is* a vector! ;-)

Comment: @Tommy: Is that true in R?  I thought a list was a fundamental data type just like a vector....

Comment: `is.vector(list()) # TRUE` ...but typically we mean an *atomic* vector when we say vector. `is.atomic(list()) # FALSE`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the ,drop=FALSE argument

```
> res <- lapply(l, function(x) x[2:nrow(x),, drop=FALSE])
> sapply(res,class)
           A            B            C 
"data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" 
> res
$A
  a
2 2
3 3

$B
  b
2 5
3 6
4 5

$C
  c
2 4
3 5
4 6
```

Comment: Yes, nothing to do with `lapply`.