# How to subset matrix to one column, maintain matrix data type, maintain row/column names?

Tags: r, matrix, subset, r-faq

When I subset a matrix to a single column, the result is of class numeric, not matrix (i.e. myMatrix[ , 5 ] to subset to the fifth column).  Is there a compact way to subset to a single column, maintain the matrix format, and maintain the row/column names without doing something complicated like:

```
matrix( myMatrix[ , 5 ] , dimnames = list( rownames( myMatrix ) , colnames( myMatrix )[ 5 ] )
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Use the `drop=FALSE` argument to `[`.

```
m <- matrix(1:10,5,2)
rownames(m) <- 1:5
colnames(m) <- 1:2
m[,1]             # vector
m[,1,drop=FALSE]  # matrix
```

Comment: I would have sworn I saw this just recently but it may have been the analogous dataframe behavior that was being questioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941985/r-how-to-subset-a-data-frame-in-a-list-and-return-data-frame

Comment: If you want to index by only the first dimension, can you use drop as follows: `m[1,,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: To give an example on statistical grounds, using Cooks' D distances, and then selecting values based on a cut off value e.g. 0.1, it will result the cooksD values with their respective number of row in the relative dataset  `cooksd<-as.data.frame(cooks.distance(ft1))
cooksD_outliers<-cooksd[cooksd>0.1,drop=FALSE,]`

Comment: result<-apply(temp,1,function(x) tapply(x, genesymbol,function(x) mean(x,na.rm=T)))     How to deal with the problem that result is a array, but actually, I want it to be a one column data frame ?  Thanks

Comment: @ShichengGuo: You should ask a new question.

Comment: How would I get this from the documentation?  I can't search `?[`

Comment: @irritable_phd_syndrom use `help("[")` or `?"["`. You need to quote any name that isn't "syntactic" (see `?Quotes` and `?Syntax` for details).

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't seem to work if the object is sticky (package).