# In R, why does selecting rows from a data frame return data as a vector if the data frame has only one column?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose we want to access data from a data frame by row.  The examples are simplified but when ordering a data frame by row names, for example, (`df[order(row.names(df)]`) we use the same technique.

If the data frame has one column, we get back an atomic vector:

```
> df
    x1
a   x
b   y
c   z

> df[1, ] # returns atomic vector
[1] x
```

If the data frame has two columns, we get back a 1-row data frame including the row name:

```
> df
    x1 x2
a   x  u
b   y  v
c   z  w 

> df[1, ] # returns data frame
   X1 X2
a  x  u
```

I don't understand why the same operation on the data frame yields two types of results depending on how many columns the frame has.

Comment: Identical questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7598674/602276 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7352254/602276

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because the default argument to `[` is `drop=TRUE`.

From `?"["`

> drop
>   For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the
>   lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for
>   extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further
>   details.

```
> dat1 <- data.frame(x=letters[1:3])
> dat2 <- data.frame(x=letters[1:3], y=LETTERS[1:3])
```

The default behaviour:

```
> dat[1, ]
     row sessionId scenarionName stepName duration
[1,]   1      1001             A    start        0

> dat[2, ]
     row sessionId scenarionName stepName duration
[1,]   2      1001             A    step1      2.2
```

Using `drop=FALSE`:

```
> dat1[1, , drop=FALSE]
  x
1 a

> dat2[1, , drop=FALSE]
  x y
1 a A
```

Comment: This is 'The R Inferno' Circle 8.1.45 http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf