# How do I delete rows from a data frame when the DF only has one column

Tags: r, dataframe

This is sort of a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672152/in-r-why-does-selecting-rows-from-a-data-frame-return-data-as-a-vector-if-the-d), but the emphasis is very different, so I'm posting it.

I have a data.frame with one column.  If I attempt to delete a row using "df[-1, ]" R returns a List.  How do I get it to return a data.frame?

Comment: I don't think the minus sign qualifies as a "very different" emphasis

Comment: That is an identical dupe. Thanks saving as the time looking for it ourselves.

Comment: No, it isn't, because if it was a dupe, then a search for "How do I delete rows from a data frame when the DF only has one column" would find it.  Which it didn't.  It only came up when I did that as a title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that R is trying to be "helpful", and simplifying your data for you.  The solution is to do the following (note two commas, not one):

```
df[-1,, drop = FALSE]
```

This will remove the specified row, and leave your data.frame otherwise untouched.