# Cannot get igraph edgelist working, ncol for matrix returns NULL

Tags: r, igraph

I have a problem with one-row matrix, I cannot load it to a directed graph

```
> network_matrix
     login      mentions weight
[1,] "rtomayko" "author" "1"   
> str(network_matrix)
 chr [1, 1:3] "rtomayko" "author" "1"
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "login" "mentions" "weight"
> typeof(network_matrix)
[1] "character"
> g = graph.edgelist(network_matrix[,1:2], directed = TRUE)
Error in graph.edgelist(network_matrix[, 1:2], directed = TRUE) : 
  graph_from_edgelist expects a matrix with two columns
>
```

3 rd column is weight and I'd like to skip it

```
> is.matrix(network_matrix)
[1] TRUE
> ncol(network_matrix)
[1] 3
```

Which is fine, but:

```
> ncol(network_matrix[,1:2])
NULL
```

Which I don't understand why is NULL and prevents igraph *structure.generators.R* code from running because of the ncol(el) != 2 check.

This is my code which worked on previous data and which I'd like to run now:

```
g = graph.edgelist(network_matrix[,1:2], directed = TRUE)
E(g)$weight=as.numeric(network_matrix[,3])
```

Thanks!

Comment: `g = graph.edgelist(network_matrix[,1:2, drop=F], directed = TRUE)`

Comment: Hi. Great, it helped. I'll accept it as soon as it's written as an SO answer, where it'll be explained what does *drop* do.

Comment: oski, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352254/how-to-subset-matrix-to-one-column-maintain-matrix-data-type-maintain-row-colu) will explain the `drop` argument .. also have a read of `?'['`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was necessary to set the drop=F

```
g = graph.edgelist(network_matrix[,1:2, drop=F], directed = TRUE)
```

thanks @user20650

case closed