# Create matrix from another matrix

Tags: r

I have matrix A with 1 column, and I want to create a new matrix B with some numbers from A. More precisely

```
B[1-10] <- A[2-6, and 11-16]
```

Do anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `B <- A[ c(2:6, 11:16), 1 ]` ?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7352254/680068

Comment: `-` is subtraction, `:` is sequence

Answer (score 4):

Say we have this example matrix:

```
# example 1 column matrix
A <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 1)
```

We can subset the 1st column and selected rows:

```
B <- A[ c(2:6, 11:16), 1 ]
dim(B)
# NULL
class(B)
# [1] "integer"
```

Notice above will give us an integer vector. To keep it as matrix after subsetting use `drop = FALSE`:

```
B <- A[ c(2:6, 11:16), 1, drop = FALSE ]
dim(B)
# [1] 11  1
class(B)
# [1] "matrix"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without example but try this:

```
B = as.matrix (c(A[2:6,1],A[11:16,1]))
```

Comment: `A[11-16,1]` is same as `A[-5,1]` meaning exclude 5th row.

Comment: This does not give desired output

Comment: Opps. Just a typoe. I mean 11:16. @zx8754