# how to extract a rectangular matrix from a symmetric matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a symmetric  matrix 562x562 and I would like to extract a submatrix from it with the first 4 rows, so with dimension 4x562, maintaining the same labels.
Any suggestion to do it in R?
Thanks

Comment: You can just do `m1[1:4, ]`

Comment: `x[1:4,]`. This is a fairly basic and common operation in R, I think it would be beneficial to go through a tutorial or two?

Comment: thanks guys, I tried with lapply, but it does not work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subset matrix to one column, maintain matrix data type, maintain row/column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352254/how-to-subset-matrix-to-one-column-maintain-matrix-data-type-maintain-row-colu)

Comment: take a look here for an explanation of the apply familiy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family?rq=1

Comment: thank you Riccardo, your first link solved me the problem of exctracting only one row with `m[1:1,,drop=FALSE]`; Using `m1[1, ]` I got a column vector instead of a row vector