# Subset a list of data.frames and return list of data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I realise this question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941985/r-how-to-subset-a-data-frame-in-a-list-and-return-data-frame) (amongst others) however I cannot seem to modify the solution(s) to fit my problem. Please mark as a duplicate or link to the existing answer if needed. Here is some example data modified slightly from the aforementioned question:

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b=c(4,5,6,5,5,5)
c=c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
A=data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)
B=data.frame(a=c,b=b,c=a)
C=data.frame(a=b,b=c,c=a)
l <- list(A, B, C)
```

I would like to generate a list of dataframes that is a subset of the original dataframes (in `l`) that match a condition. For example I might like to return all values greater than or equal to 4 with lower values replaced by `NA`'s so that my new list, `subsetl` looks as follows. (I don't care about keeping the NA's in the correct place in the dataframe.)

```
> subsetl
[[1]]
a b  c
1 NA 4 NA
2 NA 5  4
3 NA 6  5
4  4 5  6
5  5 5  7
6  6 5  8

[[2]]
a b  c
1 NA 4 NA
2  4 5 NA
3  5 6 NA
4  6 5  4
5  7 5  5
6  8 5  6

[[3]]
a  b  c
1 4 NA NA
2 5  4 NA
6  5 NA
4 5  6  4
5 5  7  5
6 5  8  6
```

I hope my example is clear enough to understand but let me know if not. This is no doubt simple using `lapply`, `sapply` or the like but I cant get the syntax right when using lists and especially when a list of dataframes is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
subsetl <- lapply(l,function(x) {
    x[x<4] <- NA
    return(x)
})
```

Result:

```
>subsetl
[[1]]
   a b  c
1 NA 4 NA
2 NA 5  4
3 NA 6  5
4  4 5  6
5  5 5  7
6  6 5  8

[[2]]
   a b  c
1 NA 4 NA
2  4 5 NA
3  5 6 NA
4  6 5  4
5  7 5  5
6  8 5  6

[[3]]
  a  b  c
1 4 NA NA
2 5  4 NA
3 6  5 NA
4 5  6  4
5 5  7  5
6 5  8  6
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, that is excellent and exactly what I was getting at despite the poor explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Another one: `mapply(replace, l, lapply(l, '<', 4), NA, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`